# Why is this php code working on my test server (mamp) but not on my webserver?

Tags: php, content-management-system

my name is Jens first off all my apologies for my english, it's not great. I am trying to make my own CMS for pictures. The pictures are uploaded to a folder. Now I am trying to display all pictures in that particular folder. By using this code.

```html
<?php
  $dirname = "../img/AFTERWORKSUP/";
  $images = glob($dirname."*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);

  foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img class="image" src="' . $image.'" />';
  }
 ?>
```

The code above works totally fine on my test server (mamp). But, when I upload it to my webserver there are no images displayed at all. The pictures are in the folder. I am sure about that.

It would be totally awesome if you would help me...
Thanks in advance Jens.

Comment: i m not sure but may be it's path issue... can u share output in console ?

Comment: could be a case of case : mac is case insensitive for paths/folder/file names.

Comment: Or could be that the permissions for the AFTERWORKSUP folder are not set correctly and the webserver cannot access? You could var_dump the `$images` array and see what the `glob()` function is outputting.

Comment: Thanks guys it was a bit of both... The variable $dirname needs to be "../img/AfterWorkSUP/". It's interesting that it works on mamp and not on my webserver! Does anybody know why ? Thanks a lot guys !